# For Drip Irrigation can I add a second backflow preventer after an anti siphon valve?

Tags: valve, irrigation

I'm installing a residential drip irrigation system for my home. I understand the need for backflow prevention and plan on using anti siphon valves. I have one area that is a full story higher than where I plan to install my valves and the rest of the system which is on our back deck. While this area will be fed from a dedicated valve -- I would rather not have to install a constant pressure mainline up to the deck to raise the valve the required 6" above the highest emitter.

In this case, could I add a second valve to the poly tubing at a highpoint to prevent backflow? If so, which kind(s) would be appropriate?

Comment: you may need to have a backflow preventer in the first place ... check your local bylaws

Comment: "a fall story higher" I presume that's a typo for "a _full_ story higher"? If so, please feel free to [edit] to correct it.

Comment: Adding a check valve will keep the water in the line and still allow the anti siphon valves to work when the water is turned off that’s how I did the exact same thing at my last house drip irrigation on the 2nd story deck, use caution if working with the black poly if the line is full of water and turned on after noon it can burn the plants.